# R - preprocessing of time series data

Tags: r

I have the following data structure, with Stocks *S*, having features *f*:

```
year S1_f1  S1_f2 S2_f1 S2_f2 S3_f1 S3_f2 Sn_f1 Sn_f2
2011   0.1    0.4  0.12  0.42   0.2   0.5     n     n
2012   0.4    0.7  0.42  0.72   0.5   0.8     n     n
2013   0.7    0.9  0.72   0.5   0.8   0.9     n     n
n        n      n     n     n     n     n     n     n
```

My original df has 10 observations but 50k+ predictors - so I want to generate more balance on the observation side.

Hence, I want to have the following dataframe:

```
year S1_f1 S1_f2 S2_f1 S2_f2 S3_f1 S3_f2 Sn_f1 Sn_f2
2011   0.1   0.4     0     0     0     0     0     0
2012   0.4   0.7     0     0     0     0     0     0
2013   0.7   0.9     0     0     0     0     0     0
2011     0     0  0.12  0.42     0     0     0     0
2012     0     0  0.42  0.72     0     0     0     0
2013     0     0  0.72   0.5     0     0     0     0
2011     0     0     0     0   0.2   0.5     0     0
2012     0     0     0     0   0.5   0.8     0     0
2013     0     0     0     0   0.8   0.9     0     0
n        0     0     0     0     0     0     n     n
```

...and so on (example values).

I want to artificially multiply my timestamps via this approach.

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert what you have into what you want using the following code:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(
  melt(setDT(s), id="year")[, grp:=gsub("_.*$","",variable)],
  year+grp~variable,
  value.var="value"
  )[order(grp,year)]
```

Output:

```
    year    grp S1_f1 S1_f2 S2_f1 S2_f2 S3_f1 S3_f2
   <int> <char> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
1:  2011     S1   0.1   0.4    NA    NA    NA    NA
2:  2012     S1   0.4   0.7    NA    NA    NA    NA
3:  2013     S1   0.7   0.9    NA    NA    NA    NA
4:  2011     S2    NA    NA  0.12  0.42    NA    NA
5:  2012     S2    NA    NA  0.42  0.72    NA    NA
6:  2013     S2    NA    NA  0.72  0.50    NA    NA
7:  2011     S3    NA    NA    NA    NA   0.2   0.5
8:  2012     S3    NA    NA    NA    NA   0.5   0.8
9:  2013     S3    NA    NA    NA    NA   0.8   0.9
```

Input:

```
structure(list(year = 2011:2013, S1_f1 = c(0.1, 0.4, 0.7), S1_f2 = c(0.4, 
0.7, 0.9), S2_f1 = c(0.12, 0.42, 0.72), S2_f2 = c(0.42, 0.72, 
0.5), S3_f1 = c(0.2, 0.5, 0.8), S3_f2 = c(0.5, 0.8, 0.9)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible way o solve your problem (note that I did not convert the data, say `df`, into a `data.table`):

```
library(data.table)

result = sub("^S(\\d)+_.*", "\\1", names(df)[-1]) |> 
  unique() |> 
  lapply(function(i) df[sprintf(c("year", "S%s_f1", "S%s_f2"), i)]) |> 
  rbindlist(use.names=TRUE, fill=TRUE) |> 
  setnafill(fill=0)

    year S1_f1 S1_f2 S2_f1 S2_f2 S3_f1 S3_f2
   <int> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
1:  2011   0.1   0.4  0.00  0.00   0.0   0.0
2:  2012   0.4   0.7  0.00  0.00   0.0   0.0
3:  2013   0.7   0.9  0.00  0.00   0.0   0.0
4:  2011   0.0   0.0  0.12  0.42   0.0   0.0
5:  2012   0.0   0.0  0.42  0.72   0.0   0.0
6:  2013   0.0   0.0  0.72  0.50   0.0   0.0
7:  2011   0.0   0.0  0.00  0.00   0.2   0.5
8:  2012   0.0   0.0  0.00  0.00   0.5   0.8
9:  2013   0.0   0.0  0.00  0.00   0.8   0.9
```

Answer (score 1):

**1) dplyr/tidyr**  Using the data `d` in the Note at the end, define a function `f` which given `g` (which can be "S1", "S2" or "S3") returns a data frame containing year and the columns whose names start with the value of `g`.  Use `Map` to apply that across those three levels giving a 3 component list and use `bind_rows` to bind them into the required form except that the zeros are NA's.   The last line converts the NA's to zero and can be omitted if NA's are ok.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

f <- function(g) cbind( year = d$year, d[startsWith(names(d), g)] )
Map(f, unique(sub("_.*", "", names(d)[-1]))) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "S") %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ replace_na(., 0)))
```

giving:

```
   S year S1_f1 S1_f2 S2_f1 S2_f2 S3_f1 S3_f2
1 S1 2011   0.1   0.4  0.00  0.00   0.0   0.0
2 S1 2012   0.4   0.7  0.00  0.00   0.0   0.0
3 S1 2013   0.7   0.9  0.00  0.00   0.0   0.0
4 S2 2011   0.0   0.0  0.12  0.42   0.0   0.0
5 S2 2012   0.0   0.0  0.42  0.72   0.0   0.0
6 S2 2013   0.0   0.0  0.72  0.50   0.0   0.0
7 S3 2011   0.0   0.0  0.00  0.00   0.2   0.5
8 S3 2012   0.0   0.0  0.00  0.00   0.5   0.8
9 S3 2013   0.0   0.0  0.00  0.00   0.8   0.9
```

**2)** Create simple wrapper around `magic::adiag` which accepts a list of data.frames.

Then create a vector `g` defining a grouping of the columns which is in the case of the example equals `c("S1", "S1", "S2", "S2", "S3", "S3")` .  Use it to split the columns of `d` into a list of data frames, `L`, one for each level of `g`.  Apply `Bdiag` which we apply to that list to create a block diagonal matrix and insert the S and year columns.

```
library(magic)

Bdiag <- function(List) do.call("adiag", Map(as.matrix, List))

g <- sub("_.*", "", names(d)[-1])
L <- tapply(as.list(d[-1]), g, as.data.frame)
data.frame(expand.grid(year = d$year, S = unique(g))[2:1], Bdiag(L))
```

**2a)** Alternately replace Bdiag with the following which is a wrapper around `Matrix::bdiag` .  This involves one more line of code but means that the code only uses base R as the Matrix package comes with R itself.

```
library(Matrix)

Bdiag <- function(List) {
  b <- bdiag(lapply(List, as.matrix))
  array(b, dim(b), dimnames = list(NULL, sapply(List, colnames)))
}
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
year S1_f1  S1_f2 S2_f1 S2_f2 S3_f1 S3_f2
2011   0.1    0.4  0.12  0.42   0.2   0.5
2012   0.4    0.7  0.42  0.72   0.5   0.8
2013   0.7    0.9  0.72   0.5   0.8   0.9"
d <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Works perfectly, the solution above also solves another problem (by creating another column with the Stocks), therefore I have accepted that one

Comment: The question didn't ask for that but I have added now.

Comment: Yeah I know, the solution above just solved that by coincidence.

Comment: I think I like the last solution, which was previously numbered (3), best so I have re-arranged the presentation.